# I need to get a blank json field on my Django and collect it as error

Tags: python, json, django

So far this is my code.

```py
def post(self, request):
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        if not request.data['valor_sensor']:
            request.data['valor_sensor'] = "ERRO"

    serializer = serializers.EventosSerializer(data=request.data)
    
    serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATE
```

Here are the models:

```
from django.db import models

class Eventos(models.Model):
    horario = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    valor_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And here's my serializer.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Eventos

#criando o serializers que transforma em JSON

class EventosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Eventos
        fields =  ['id', 'horario', 'tag_sensor', 'valor_sensor']
```

I need to take the field `valor_sensor`, from this json, and when I collect it, IF IT IS BLANK, I need to transform it into the string `"ERROR"`. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Is serializer a Django model object? If so, can you post the model class?

Comment: Edited for you @sytech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this perhaps one a few ways:

You can use [field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) to transform it in your serializer:

```py
class EventosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Eventos
        fields =  ['id', 'horario', 'tag_sensor', 'valor_sensor']
    def validate_valor_sensor(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = 'ERROR'
        # other validation steps
        return value
```

Or object level validation

```py
class EventosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        if not data.get('valor_sensor'):
            data['valor_sensor'] = 'ERROR'
        return super().validate(data)
```

You can set a default on your model:

```py
class Eventos(models.Model):
    ...
    valor_sensor = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='ERROR')
```

You can override your model's  `save` method:

```py
class Eventos(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.valor_sensor:
            self.valor_sensor = 'ERROR'
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried all 3 and I still got the error saying that the field is blank from the api.

I'm trying to POST on the API via the rest framework localhost server.

Comment: @LucasOutor can you update the question with the full code in your view and any error/log messages?

Comment: You probably want to pass `partial=True` when creating the serializer object or set `required=False` on the serializer class for the field.

Comment: It worked after I put that that the field could be blank and I used the second option! Thank you!! @sytech